# Edge automatically refreshes web pages

Tags: windows-10-mobile, microsoft-edge, lumia-540

I'm using a Microsoft Lumia 540 with Windows 10 Mobile and the Edge browser refreshes automatically. Many times I have to  watch a video from YouTube again or have to read an article again and again. Do anyone have any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: I think this is a feature of the Edge browser. I have experienced the same with my Lumia 950XL. What did you do for the page to reload?

Comment: I did nothing it just refresh its own.

Comment: Is this happening when your switching between apps, or does it happen while you're watching the video or reading an article?

Comment: When you say refreshing, do you mean stuff keeps moving about on the page, or it completely blanks out before showing the page, and repeating constantly? Have you got some example webpages that this happens on?